# How to dynamically change data source in RDLC report with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer

I want to create a report that contains order data from my Google sheet data and show this report by a report viewer control. I'm using the Microsoft report rdlc extension to create it.

Because Google sheet data is not a relational database, so I create a dummy dataset by using objects (I created a simple class with 2 properties: OrderID and OrderName), and I connect the tablix with the dataset.

But I want to dynamically add rows or columns to the tablix due to my user's selection so I'm trying to create a new data source for reportviewer control. The problem is when the name of the data source in my code is matched with the data source ("DataSet1") in the 2report.rdlc file, it worked. But if I try to create a new data source with a different name like "NewData", I got an error like: "data source instance has not been assign to the dataset 'Dataset1'".

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?
Please tell me if you have any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    ' Create a new DataTable object
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable("myTable")
    Dim dtSet As New DataSet("NewdtSet")

    ' Add columns to the DataTable
    dataTable.Columns.Add("OrderID", GetType(Integer))
    dataTable.Columns.Add("OrderName", GetType(String))
    dataTable.Columns.Add("OrderContent", GetType(String))

    ' Add rows to the DataTable
    dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Row1")
    dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Row2")
    dataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Row3", "ABCMartShoes")
    dtSet.Tables.Add(dataTable)
    Dim dataSource As New ReportDataSource("DataNew", dtSet.Tables("myTable"))

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource)

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

Here is my dummy dataset

[image]

UPDATE:
Here is my report tablix when I run the code above (I change the ReportDataSource name to "DataSet1"). As you guys can see, i tried to add new column "Order Content", but it was not shown on report

[image]

Comment: I dont understand the problem. SRSS expects the DataSet to match the name it needs, eg DataSet1, DataSet2. So why not use these names or if you want create one for NewData?

Comment: Yes, because as you see in the picture, I created 2 properties for the DataSet1, but in fact, there are more than 2 properties such as Order Date, Order Quantity,etc. And I can not set these properties to be fixed because I dont know what properties users have in their database. So I need to create a new dataset or replace the existing dataset with new properties. But I failed to do it right now

Comment: In additional, it worked when the dataset name matches, but the tablix is connected to the DataSet1( that has only 2 columns), so even when I tried to add new column (Order Content), the tablix does not show the added column. What I want is to dynamically change the existing value in the dataset(i.e: tablix's column) on runtime

Comment: You're doing it right, the only difference between code I have that does this is mines c# and I set the namespace and prefixes:  
`ds.Namespace = "http://tempuri.org"`    
`ds.Prefix = "MyPrefix"`    
`ds.Locale = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")`    
`dt.Locale = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")`

Comment: Could you please tell me what does this code do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your dataset defined in the RDLC file contains all of the fields of both tables. A field does not have to actually be used in the Report, just defined. So when you change to DataNew table the field OrderContent is in the RDLC file. If you do that all you need to do is fix the following:

```
Dim dataSource As New ReportDataSource("DataNew", dtSet.Tables("myTable"))
```

to

```
Dim dataSource As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dtSet.Tables("myTable"))
```

Comment: yeah I understand that I have to define the field for dataset, but as I mentioned above, I don't know what user's database will be so I'm finding a way to dinamically add field for dataset. For example, if I define 2 field "OrderId" and "OrderName", in runtime I want to add a new field "OrderContent". Is that possible?